# Ambiguous tag: switching

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags

There are [134 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/switching) using the [switching](/questions/tagged/switching) tag. Most are using it in the sense of "changing from one thing to another," e.g. ["Switching from UIViewController to UITabBarController."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830375) However, there are a couple that are actually talking about the concept of network switching, e.g. ["Same subnet in different VLAN s."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131717/same-subnet-in-different-vlan-s) The tag has no wiki.

Opinions about what to do with the tag?

Comment: I favor burnination without further review; this tag doesn't appear to have any categorization benefit whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

I think the questions need to be reviewed.  Not for the [first example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13830375) you gave, but the [second example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131717/same-subnet-in-different-vlan-s) is off-topic.  These should be voted to close (and flagged if not there's not enough close vote velocity) for being off topic.

This is in addition to general quality guidelines that should be checked on any question with the tag.

For cases in the first example, remove the tag.  "Switching" is *way* to generic.

However, in cases like the second, I say that a more specific tag should be used if one is available (or one created, perhaps [network-switch](/questions/tagged/network-switch) if it's a valid on topic question for Stack Overflow that deals with programming against network switches).

Comment: Insisting that questions in a bad tag get reviewed first for quality issues pretty much guarantees that tags will never get removed, or will be removed "the hard way," one at a time.